# AS3 - How can you make sure your XML loads

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, loading

I do not need any debugging with my code, i'm looking more for a method.

Here's my issue. I'm developing a company dashboard that will be loading on multiple large screen televisions company wide. Each Screen will load my flash application to display a wide range of information. This brings up my issue... XML.

Right now i run my application locally while I'm developing. Everything works great, and even when I've tested on a single TV it runs fine. However prior to developing this application i made another that was a "band aid fix" for what they had prior to my employment. That application works well but probably once a week it fails to load and all the content goes blank. After 1 day of blank info it reloads and continues working.

In my new app i'm trying to plan around this issue i'm already seeing. What i would like to do is try loading the xml, if it fails to try the same function over again 3 times. If it fails 3 times, then it should be broken. :)

To me that sounds like a try/catch statement, but i can't seem to get it to work the way i want. I feel as if this is something i'm thinking way too much on it.

```
function loadXML ()
    var i:Number = 0;
    do {
        try{
            XMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("myXMLURL"));
        } catch (error:Error) {
            i++
          }
        }
    while(i < 3)
}
```

Any Feedback or any other methods of making sure the xml will not fail would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a loop like that, you should use the inbuilt events that are dispatched in these situations like [`IOErrorEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IOErrorEvent.html).

If you attach a listener to the `URLLoader` loading the XML, you'll be able to try again in the `IOErrorEvent` handler:

```
function loadXML():void
{
    var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    ldr.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, error);
    ldr.load( new URLRequest("document.xml") );
}


function error(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    loadXML();
}
```

[Here is a list of other Events](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#eventSummary) that `URLLoader` dispatches in similar situations.

Comment: Can't believe i didn't think about that. I've been working around loops for a while trying to get it to work, but that's pretty self explanatory. 

I'll try that out.

if there are any other ideas keep em coming! Thanks again!